# Wort für jemanden, der Abitur macht

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es im Deutschen ein Wort für jemanden, der das *Abitur* bzw. die *mittlere Reife* ablegt? Z.B.

> Die Schüler, die letztes Jahr das Chemie-Abitur gemacht haben, schnitten schlecht ab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Für Abitur ist das gesuchte Wort in Deutschland *Abiturient*; es umfasst Schüler vor, während als auch nach der Abiturprüfung.

In Österreich heißt das Abitur Matura, der Abiturient somit *Maturant*, in der deutschsprachigen Schweiz *Maturand*.

Für die Mittlere Reife ist mir nur das Wort *Realschulabsolvent* eingefallen.

---

For *Abitur* it is [Abiturient](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abiturient), for *mittlere Reife* I'm only aware of the clumsy construction *Realschulabsolvent*.

In Austria *Matura* corresponds to Abitur, so *Maturant* (in Switzerland: *Maturand*) takes the position of *Abiturient*.

So your sentence would be:

> Die Abiturienten des Vorjahres im Fach Chemie schnitten schlecht ab.

Comment: Und warum ergänzt du nicht einfach die deutsche Variante der Antwort?

Comment: Irgendwie klingt die Variante hier holpriger als die aus der Frage.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ich habe den Beispielsatz auch nicht als bessere Variante verkauft, sondern als eine, die das Wort *Abiturient* verwendet. Da Chemie (in Bayern) ein eher exotisches Abiturfach ist, wird der Satz eine Spur komplizierter, *holprig* würde ich ihn aber sicher nicht nennen..